# angular-translate didn't attempt to use the fallback language if the preferred language failed to load

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

When using angular-translate to localize my Angular app, the fallback language is not attempted if the preferred language (via static file loader) failed to load or doesn't exist for any reason.

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'locale-',
    suffix: '.json'
});
$translateProvider
    .preferredLanguage('ja')
    .fallbackLanguage('en');
```

The plnkr is available: http://plnkr.co/edit/tHrBeY0Ur0rhp0xNuWpA?p=preview

If there is an empty locale-ja.json file, then the fallback is loaded correctly. 
This as pointed out might be a library bug. Has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: It's a library bug. report a bug (or found the existing one) on the github account of the projet.

Answer (score 3):

FallbackLanguge function have another purpose - if a translation-table doesn't have a specific key, the translation from the fallback language will be used.
If you want to specify default language, you can use wildcard in registerAvailableLanguageKeys function:

```
.registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en, da'], {
    'en_US': 'en',
    'en_UK': 'en',
    'da_DK': 'da',
    '*': 'en'
})
```

In this example 'en' is the default language. It will load if the preferred language doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Currently stumbled upon the same problem, and the only way I can solve it is by adding `$translateProvider.use()` option. so it would look like this:

```
 $translateProvider
    .preferredLanguage('ja')
    .use('ja')
    .fallbackLanguage('en');
```